# how to merge branches on GitHub website, besides pull request

Tags: github

This question is specific to GitHub website.

I know that a pull request merges changes from a feature branch to the main/master branch, but how can I do the reverse and merge any updates from main/master into the feature branch. And also, how can I merge between two branches, neither of which is the main/master branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to say it, but that's still a PR.  Just set which two branches you want to go into, and from, in the PR.  It there another reason to avoid a PR in this case?
[image]