# merged changes isn't considered as a change in the branch that i merged into

Tags: git, github, git-merge

i have a simple question, if i have a branch called `a` then i checked out another branch from that one, called `b`, i made some changes in `b`, commited, then pushed it, and merged `b` back into `a`.

now `a` gets the changes locally on my machine but not in the github website, and `a` doesn't consider the changes that i've merged as a change in branch `a` so i can't manually commit then push to `a` so that it reflects on the github site. how to solve that ?

i tried to change the merged file then push manually, but why would i need to change the file after the merge if i already made all the changes before merging.

Comment: did you not push after the merge?

Comment: i didn't push into branch `a` but i would do it if i can, that's the problem after i merge `b` into `a`, `a` has no changes to commit and push so i have to make further unnecessary edits in it if i want to push.

Comment: `a` has no changes to commit but it still has new commits that haven't been pushed yet (the ones you merged). `git status` should say something like *ahead of 'origin/a' by X commits.*

Comment: after i merge `b` into `a`, running `git status` in `a` gives (nothing to commit, working tree clean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and merged b back into a.

If you merged [it online through PR (Pull Request)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72873822/6309), then you would need to refresh a locally.

If you merge it locally, then it depends on how b was merge to a, especially if "`a` has no changes to commit and push".

```bash
git switch a
git merge b
git push
```

Comment: i merge locally, and `a` doesn't have changes to commit before i merge `b`, then after i merge `b` into `a`, that doesn't change it's still (nothing to commit, working tree clean) when running git status in `a` (although i made changes in `b` before merging it back to `a`)

Comment: @EpsilonCode Do you see commits in b, compared to a, when you do a `git log --oneline --graph --all --branches --decorate`?

Comment: oh, yes i see the commits, thanks, now i understand, it says (nothing to commit) not because it didn't consider it as a change that i have to commit but because it commits it, all i had to do was to push.
but it's a bit unclear for git to say (nothing to commit) after i merge changes into the branch (I'm just used to committing then pushing not git committing for me), however thanks for your help.

Comment: @EpsilonCode Yes, `git merge` is purely local.